# Port 9553 (from Firebase) blocked by webhost, can't find a way to successfully cURL over alternate port

Tags: nest-api

I'm using PHP and cURL with the REST api, and even though I can cURL the initial Nest Developer api endpoint, once it redirects to Firebase's url it's over port 9553, which my webhost has blocked (no chance to get opened up either). The connection times out and throws the 'could not connect to host' error.

My code is working fine, I can run it on my local server with no problems.

I'm new at using cURL, what are my options? It seems to me that the problem is the port Firebase is insisting on using. I can cURL a number of different locations, over :80 and :443 without problem, just not Firebase's url. Will I need to run through a proxy in order to access the data?

Or, is this something that might be solved by using Firebase's PHP library? I'm not super interested in using it if I don't have to, cURL would do the job nicely, and I don't know really know how it works.

Comment: This is a problem for me also, as many corporate users are behind firewalls that block this port.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get around the redirects with REST, they point to specific ports and hosts in Nest's cloud.

What is wrong with Firebase's Web Sockets client? It is more performant than REST.

Comment: Not anything wrong with them, I just don't have experience using PHP libraries. I've looked at the documentation, but I don't really know where to start.How do I connect the Nest API with a Firebase app, or are they already connected?

Answer (score 0):

joshguerette,
Is your firewall blocking that port?

You can open the port from your c# code with this:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common;
private void AddPortToFirewall(int portNumber, string name) 
{
    INetFwMgr icfMgr = null;
    try
    {
        Type TicfMgr = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr");
        icfMgr = (INetFwMgr)Activator.CreateInstance(TicfMgr);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Failed in AddPortToFirewall.Activator " + portNumber.ToString() + " " + name + " " + ex.ToString());
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        INetFwProfile profile;
        INetFwOpenPort portClass;
        Type TportClass = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWOpenPort");
        portClass = (INetFwOpenPort)Activator.CreateInstance(TportClass);

        // Get the current profile
        profile = icfMgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile;

        // Set firewall enabled
        if (!profile.FirewallEnabled)
            profile.FirewallEnabled = true;

        // Set the port properties
        portClass.Scope = NET_FW_SCOPE_.NET_FW_SCOPE_ALL;
        portClass.Enabled = true;
        portClass.Name = name;
        portClass.Port = portNumber;
        portClass.Protocol = NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_.NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP;

        // Add the port to the ICF Permissions List
        bool portExisted = false;
        foreach (INetFwOpenPort p in profile.GloballyOpenPorts)
        {
            if (p.Port == portNumber && p.Name == name)
            {
                portExisted = true;
                Debug.WriteLine("Windows Firewall inbound list:" + p.Port + " " + p.Name);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!portExisted)
        {
            profile.GloballyOpenPorts.Add(portClass);
            Debug.WriteLine("ServicePort " + portNumber.ToString() + " " + name + " was added into Windows Firewall inbound list.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ServicePort " + portNumber.ToString() + " " + name + " has already in Windows Firewall inbound list.");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Failed in AddPortToFirewall " + portNumber.ToString() + " " + name + " " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm on shared hosting, so I have no access to the firewall. Also, my application is PHP.